# Removing space from variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Why is variable `wifiname` empty in `show profile` command?

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN ('"netsh wlan show profiles"') DO (
Set myvar=%%G
SET wifiname=%myvar:~1%
@echo '%%G'
@echo '%wifiname%'
netsh wlan show profile name="%wifiname%" key=clear >> wp.txt
)
```

If I pass `%%G` directly (without double quotes), it is working excluding networks with multiple words delimited with space. Leading space is ignored.

With double quotes, full network name is passed, byt leading space is problem for each network name...

Simplest solution - remove leading space from `%%G` and pass this result in double quotes to the final command... How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I remove the leading space from a variable?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN ('netsh wlan show profiles') DO (
  SET _temp=%%G
  SET wifiname=!_temp:~1!
  netsh wlan show profile name="!wifiname!" key=clear
)
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test

Profile virginmedia3954038 on interface Wireless Network Connection:
=======================================================================

Applied: All User Profile

Profile information
-------------------
    Version                : 1
    Type                   : Wireless LAN
    Name                   : virginmedia3954038
    Control options        :
        Connection mode    : Connect automatically
        Network broadcast  : Connect only if this network is broadcasting
        AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks
```

...

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: works, any clear explanation when use % or %% or %_% or ! and etc.?

Comment: @Jerry See the last two links I added.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question literal there are several ways to accomplish that.

The most simple in your case is to use a better a `For /f` which
uses also the space as `"delims=: "`

Provided you have a similar output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan show profiles

Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    <none>

User profiles
-------------
    All User Profile     : WLan foo bar
    All User Profile     : Router
    All User Profile     : dLink Wireless
    Current User Profile : optimumwifi

token= 1    2     3        * (rest)
forVar            %%F      \___%%G______/

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Taking into account that

- leading delimiters are ignored and
- adjacent ones are counted as only one,

use

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SU_1410873.cmd
@Echo off
For /F "tokens=3* delims=: " %%F IN ('
    netsh wlan show profiles ^| Findstr /C:"    " ^|Findstr ":"
') DO echo netsh wlan show profile name="%%G" key=clear
```

To get these (for demonstration only echoed) commands:

```
> SU_1410873.cmd
netsh wlan show profile name="WLan foo bar" key=clear
netsh wlan show profile name="Router" key=clear
netsh wlan show profile name="dLink Wireless" key=clear
netsh wlan show profile name="optimumwifi" key=clear
```